# Spring cloud stream kafka aggregate use new instance of autowired bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Is there a way to use new instance of Autowired bean inside Kafka Streams aggregate??

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class MessageReceiver {

    @StreamListener(target = Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public KStream<String, List<CustomEvent>> process(KStream<String, Event> eventKStream) {

        JsonSerde<EventAggregator> eventAggregatorJsonSerde = new JsonSerde<>(EventAggregator.class);

        TimeWindowedKStream<String, Event> timeWindowedKStream = eventKStream
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(60000).advanceBy(30000));

        timeWindowedKStream
                .aggregate(
                        EventAggregator::new, // how to use Autowired bean here, which is different for different window and different key
                        ((key, value, aggregator) -> aggregator.add(value)),
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), eventAggregatorJsonSerde)
                );

        // continues...
    }
```

Is there a way to use autowired bean instead of EventAggregator::new ??

**EventAggregator.java**

```
public class EventAggregator {

    //@Autowired
    //private SomeClass someClass; // this is null as of now, since spring can't autowire inside a non managed bean

    List<CustomEvent> customEventList = new ArrayList<>();  
    FIFOMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(4); // map which stores only 4 value

    public EventAggregator add(Event event) {   
        map.put(new Date().toString(), event.getValue());       
        generateCustomEvent(); // when I have 4 values, I need to do some operation and generate custom event
        return this;
    }

    private void generateCustomEvent() {
        if (map.size() == 4) {
            // someClass complex operation
            CustomEvent e = new CustomEvent("", "", "");
            customEventList.add(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, What is the motivation for using that as an autowired bean? That instantiation ((`EventAggregator::new`) is triggered by Kafka Streams based on new key/window etc. If you autowire that as a bean, Spring will manage that as a singleton bean. I am not sure, if that is what you want in this case.

Comment: @sobychako i neee to autowire few fields inside EventAggregator. Since spring can't autowire inside a non managed bean, I'm planning to use autowired aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, the instantiation of `EventAggregator::new` is triggered by Kafka Streams. If you want to access spring beans inside this object, one way you can make that work is by providing a constructor that takes the Spring application context and then explicitly query for the beans inside the class (for e.g using `getBean()`) method. You can autowire the context in the main class and then pass that along with the `EventAggregator` constructor.